# The test accuracy remains the same after being pruned

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network, resnet, vgg-net, pruning

I recently tried to run the offical code from the repository "Filter Pruning via Geometric Median for Deep Convolutional Neural Networks Acceleration" by Yang He. I found that everything went well when I tried pruning the Resnet(the accuracy changes). However, as long as I pruned the VGG, The test accuracy reamained the same after being pruned. I don't think it is reasonable but I just don't know what is wrong with the code. How come the accuracy is not changing? And I have already tried almost every mean that I thought might be useful to get the problem tackled, but clearly, none of them worked.So I decided to reach out to you guys for help!
So thankful of your help! Hope you guys may have a very well day.

I hope that the Mask will work(obviously this pruning technique is not working)
The code is shown below, and I omitted the training and testing part.

```
class Mask:
    def __init__(self, model):
        self.model_size = {}
        self.model_length = {}
        self.compress_rate = {}
        self.distance_rate = {}
        self.mat = {}
        self.model = model
        self.mask_index = []
        self.filter_small_index = {}
        self.filter_large_index = {}
        self.similar_matrix = {}
        self.norm_matrix = {}
        self.cfg = [64, 64, 'M', 128, 128, 'M', 256, 256, 256, 256, 'M', 512, 512, 512, 512, 'M', 512, 512, 512, 512, 'M']
    def get_codebook(self, weight_torch, compress_rate, length):
        #this def appears with no use
        weight_vec = weight_torch.view(length)
        weight_np = weight_vec.cpu().numpy()

        weight_abs = np.abs(weight_np)
        weight_sort = np.sort(weight_abs)

        threshold = weight_sort[int(length * (1 - compress_rate))]
        weight_np[weight_np <= -threshold] = 1
        weight_np[weight_np >= threshold] = 1
        weight_np[weight_np != 1] = 0

        print("codebook done")
        return weight_np

    def get_filter_codebook(self, weight_torch, compress_rate, length):
        # print("Entering get_filter_codebook...")
        #theis print statement above is working properly
        codebook = np.ones(length)
        if len(weight_torch.size()) == 4:
            # print("Entering the main branch of get_filter_codebook...")
            #this print statement above is working properly
            filter_pruned_num = int(weight_torch.size()[0] * (1 - compress_rate))
            weight_vec = weight_torch.view(weight_torch.size()[0], -1)
            norm2 = torch.norm(weight_vec, 2, 1)
            norm2_np = norm2.cpu().numpy()
            filter_index = norm2_np.argsort()[:filter_pruned_num]
            kernel_length = weight_torch.size()[1] * weight_torch.size()[2] * weight_torch.size()[3]
            for x in range(0, len(filter_index)):
                codebook[filter_index[x] * kernel_length: (filter_index[x] + 1) * kernel_length] = 0
            print("filter codebook done")
            #this print statement above is working properly
        else:
            pass
        return codebook

    def get_filter_index(self, weight_torch, compress_rate, length):
        #this def appears with no use
        if len(weight_torch.size()) == 4:
            print("filter index PREPARE")
            filter_pruned_num = int(weight_torch.size()[0] * (1 - compress_rate))
            weight_vec = weight_torch.view(weight_torch.size()[0], -1)
            norm1 = torch.norm(weight_vec, 1, 1)
            norm1_np = norm1.cpu().numpy()
            norm2 = torch.norm(weight_vec, 2, 1)
            norm2_np = norm2.cpu().numpy()
            filter_small_index = []
            filter_large_index = []
            filter_large_index = norm2_np.argsort()[filter_pruned_num:]
            filter_small_index = norm2_np.argsort()[:filter_pruned_num]
            norm1_sort = np.sort(norm1_np)
            threshold = norm1_sort[int (weight_torch.size()[0] * (1-compress_rate))]
            kernel_length = weight_torch.size()[1] * weight_torch.size()[2] * weight_torch.size()[3]
            print("filter index done")
        else:
            pass
        return filter_small_index, filter_large_index

    def get_filter_similar(self, weight_torch, compress_rate, distance_rate, length, dist_type="l2"):
        codebook = np.ones(length)
        if len(weight_torch.size()) == 4:
            filter_pruned_num = int(weight_torch.size()[0] * (1 - compress_rate))
            similar_pruned_num = int(weight_torch.size()[0] * distance_rate)
            weight_vec = weight_torch.view(weight_torch.size()[0], -1)

            if dist_type == "l2" or "cos":
                norm = torch.norm(weight_vec, 2, 1)
                norm_np = norm.cpu().numpy()
            elif dist_type == "l1":
                norm = torch.norm(weight_vec, 1, 1)
                norm_np = norm.cpu().numpy()
            filter_small_index = []
            filter_large_index = []
            filter_large_index = norm_np.argsort()[filter_pruned_num:]
            filter_small_index = norm_np.argsort()[:filter_pruned_num]
            indices = torch.LongTensor(filter_large_index).cuda()
            weight_vec_after_norm = torch.index_select(weight_vec, 0, indices).cpu().numpy()
            # for euclidean distance
            if dist_type == "l2" or "l1":
                similar_matrix = distance.cdist(weight_vec_after_norm, weight_vec_after_norm, 'euclidean')
            elif dist_type == "cos":  # for cos similarity
                similar_matrix = 1 - distance.cdist(weight_vec_after_norm, weight_vec_after_norm, 'cosine')
            similar_sum = np.sum(np.abs(similar_matrix), axis=0)
            similar_large_index = similar_sum.argsort()[similar_pruned_num:]
            similar_small_index = similar_sum.argsort()[:  similar_pruned_num]
            similar_index_for_filter = [filter_large_index[i] for i in similar_small_index]
            kernel_length = weight_torch.size()[1] * weight_torch.size()[2] * weight_torch.size()[3]
            for x in range(0, len(similar_index_for_filter)):
                codebook[
                similar_index_for_filter[x] * kernel_length: (similar_index_for_filter[x] + 1) * kernel_length] = 0
            # print("similar index done")
            #this print statement above is working properly
        else:
            pass
        return codebook

    def convert2tensor(self, x):
        x = torch.FloatTensor(x)
        return x
    def init_length(self):
        for index, (name, param) in enumerate(self.model.named_parameters()):
            self.model_size[index] = param.size()
        for index1 in self.model_size:
            for index2 in range(0, len(self.model_size[index1])):
                if index2 == 0:
                    self.model_length[index1] = self.model_size[index1][0]
                else:
                    self.model_length[index1] *= self.model_size[index1][index2]
    def init_rate(self, rate_norm_per_layer, rate_dist_per_layer, pre_cfg=True):
        cfg = [64, 64, 128, 128, 256, 256, 256, 256, 512, 512, 512, 512, 512, 512, 512, 512]
        cfg_index = 0
        for index, item in enumerate(self.model.named_parameters()):
            print(f"Layer {index} is in self.mask_index")
            #this print statement above is working properly
            self.compress_rate[index] = 1
            self.distance_rate[index] = 1
            if len(item[1].size()) == 4:
                print(item[1].size())
                if not pre_cfg:
                    self.compress_rate[index] = rate_norm_per_layer
                    self.distance_rate[index] = rate_dist_per_layer
                    self.mask_index.append(index)
                    print(item[0], "self.mask_index", self.mask_index)
                else:
                    self.compress_rate[index] = rate_norm_per_layer
                    self.distance_rate[index] = 1 - cfg[cfg_index] / item[1].size()[0]
                    self.mask_index.append(index)
                    print(item[0], "self.mask_index", self.mask_index, cfg_index, cfg[cfg_index], item[1].size()[0],
                          self.distance_rate[index], )
                    print("self.distance_rate", self.distance_rate)
                    cfg_index += 1

    def init_mask(self, rate_norm_per_layer, rate_dist_per_layer, dist_type):
        print("Entering init_mask...")
        #this print statement above is working properly
        self.init_rate(rate_norm_per_layer, rate_dist_per_layer, pre_cfg=True)
        for index, (name, param) in enumerate(self.model.named_parameters()):
            if index in self.mask_index:
                self.mat[index] = self.get_filter_codebook(param.data, self.compress_rate[index],
                                                           self.model_length[index])
                self.mat[index] = self.convert2tensor(self.mat[index])
                self.mat[index] = self.mat[index].cuda()
                # print("Calling get_filter_similar...")
                #this print statement above is working properly
                self.similar_matrix[index] = self.get_filter_similar(param.data, self.compress_rate[index],
                                                                     self.distance_rate[index],
                                                                     self.model_length[index], dist_type=dist_type)
                self.similar_matrix[index] = self.convert2tensor(self.similar_matrix[index])
                self.similar_matrix[index] = self.similar_matrix[index].cuda()
        print("mask Ready")
        #this print statement above is working properly

    def do_mask(self):
        # print("Executing do_mask...")
        for index, (name, param) in enumerate(self.model.named_parameters()):
            if index in self.mask_index:
                a = param.data.view(self.model_length[index])
                b = a * self.mat[index]
                param.data = b.view(self.model_size[index])
        print("mask Done")
        #this print statement above is working properly
    def do_similar_mask(self):
        for index, (name, param) in enumerate(self.model.named_parameters()):
            if index in self.mask_index:
                a = param.data.view(self.model_length[index])
                b = a * self.similar_matrix[index]
                param.data = b.view(self.model_size[index])
        print("mask similar Done")
        #this print statement above is working properly
    def do_grad_mask(self):
        for index, (name, param) in enumerate(self.model.named_parameters()):
            if index in self.mask_index:
                a = param.grad.data.view(self.model_length[index])
                b = a * self.mat[index]
                b = b * self.similar_matrix[index]
                param.grad.data = b.view(self.model_size[index])
        print("grad zero Done")
        #this print statement above is working properly
    def if_zero(self):
        for index, (name, param) in enumerate(self.model.named_parameters()):
            if (index in self.mask_index):
                # if index == 0:
                a = param.data.view(self.model_length[index])
                b = a.cpu().numpy()

                # print(
                #     "number of nonzero weight is %d, zero is %d" % (np.count_nonzero(b), len(b) - np.count_nonzero(b)))

m = Mask(model)
m.init_length()
print("-*-" * 10 + "\n\tone epoch begin\n" + "-*-" * 10)
print("remaining ratio of pruning : Norm is %f" % args.rate_norm)
print("reducing ratio of pruning : Distance is %f" % args.rate_dist)
print("total remaining ratio is %f" % (args.rate_norm - args.rate_dist))
#Test before pruning
val_acc_1, val_los_1 = test(1, model, ewc, test_loader)
print(" accu before is: %.3f %%" % val_acc_1)

#Test for a single pruning
m.model = model
m.init_mask(args.rate_norm, args.rate_dist, args.dist_type)
m.do_mask()
m.do_similar_mask()
model = m.model
model.cuda()
val_acc_2, val_los_2 = test(2, model, ewc, test_loader)
print(" accu after is: %s %%" % val_acc_2)

#Pruning
#i guess this is where the problem occurs. The test accuracy remains the same after applying the Mask
#However all of the print sentences work and they print properly, so i actually dont know what is the problem
best_prec1 = 0.
for epoch in range(args.epochs):
    train_acc, train_los = train(epoch, model, ewc, train_loader)
    prec1, test_los_mid = test(epoch, model, ewc, test_loader)
    if epoch % args.epoch_prune == 0 or epoch == args.epochs - 1:
        m.model = model
        m.if_zero()
        m.init_mask(args.rate_norm, args.rate_dist, args.dist_type)
        m.do_mask()
        m.do_similar_mask()
        m.if_zero()
        model = m.model
        model = model.cuda()
        val_acc, val_los = test(epoch, model, ewc, test_loader)
    is_best = val_acc > best_prec1
    best_prec1 = max(prec1, best_prec1)
    state = {
        'epoch': epoch + 1,
        'state_dict': model.state_dict(),
        'best_prec1': best_prec1,
        'optimizer': optimizer.state_dict()
        # 'cfg': model.cfg
    }
    torch.save(state, args.path + ('pruned_%s_%s%s_r%s.pth.tar' % ('cifar10', 'vgg', 19, 0.5)))
    # measure elapsed time
    # epoch_time.update(time.time() - start_time)
    start_time = time.time()
```

here is the vgg network:

```
def weights_init(m):
    # print('=> weights init')
    if isinstance(m, nn.Conv2d):
        nn.init.kaiming_normal_(m.weight, mode='fan_out', nonlinearity='relu')
        # nn.init.normal_(m.weight, 0, 0.1)
        if m.bias is not None:
            m.bias.data.zero_()
    elif isinstance(m, nn.Linear):
        # nn.init.xavier_normal(m.weight)
        nn.init.normal_(m.weight, 0, 0.01)
        nn.init.constant_(m.bias, 0)
    elif isinstance(m, nn.BatchNorm2d):
        # Note that BN's running_var/mean are
        # already initialized to 1 and 0 respectively.
        if m.weight is not None:
            m.weight.data.fill_(1.0)
        if m.bias is not None:
            m.bias.data.zero_()

defaultcfg = {
    11: [64, 'M', 128, 'M', 256, 256, 'M', 512, 512, 'M', 512, 512],
    13: [64, 64, 'M', 128, 128, 'M', 256, 256, 'M', 512, 512, 'M', 512, 512],
    16: [64, 64, 'M', 128, 128, 'M', 256, 256, 256, 'M', 512, 512, 512, 'M', 512, 512, 512],
    19: [64, 64, 'M', 128, 128, 'M', 256, 256, 256, 256, 'M', 512, 512, 512, 512, 'M', 512, 512, 512, 512],
}


class VGG(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, dataset='cifar10', depth=19, init_weights=True, cfg=None, affine=True, batchnorm=True):
        super(VGG, self).__init__()
        if cfg is None:
            cfg = defaultcfg[depth]
        self._AFFINE = affine
        self.feature = self.make_layers(cfg, batchnorm, dataset)
        self.dataset = dataset
        if dataset == 'cifar10' or dataset == 'cinic-10':
            num_classes = 10
        elif dataset == 'cifar100':
            num_classes = 100
        elif dataset == 'tiny_imagenet':
            num_classes = 200
        elif dataset == 'mnist':
            num_classes = 10
        else:
            raise NotImplementedError("Unsupported dataset " + dataset)
        self.classifier = nn.Linear(cfg[-1], num_classes)
        if init_weights:
            self.apply(weights_init)
        # if pretrained:
        #     model.load_state_dict(model_zoo.load_url(model_urls['vgg11_bn']))

    def make_layers(self, cfg, batch_norm=False, dataset='mnist'):
        layers = []
        in_channels = 1 if dataset == 'mnist' else 3
        for v in cfg:
            if v == 'M':
                layers += [nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2)]
            else:
                conv2d = nn.Conv2d(in_channels, v, kernel_size=3, padding=1, bias=False)
                if batch_norm:
                    layers += [conv2d, nn.BatchNorm2d(v, affine=self._AFFINE), nn.ReLU(inplace=True)]
                else:
                    layers += [conv2d, nn.ReLU(inplace=True)]
                in_channels = v
        return nn.Sequential(*layers)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.feature(x)
        if self.dataset == 'tiny_imagenet':
            x = nn.AvgPool2d(4)(x)
        elif self.dataset == 'mnist':
            x = nn.AvgPool2d(2)(x)
        else:
            x = nn.AvgPool2d(2)(x)
        x = x.view(x.size(0), -1)
        y = self.classifier(x)
        return y
```

the link of the offical code is[text](https://github.com/he-y/filter-pruning-geometric-median) here

Comment: Test accuracy not changing after pruning is not an actual problem, you need to clarify why you think its a problem.

Comment: thanks for the reply Dr.Snoopy! The accuracy is changing when pruning Resnet while not changing when pruning VGG.  And the official code supports pruning of VGG architecture. So i basically don't know why

Comment: Yes sure but again you are not saying why accuracy not changing is a problem.

Comment: I really appreciate your reply Dr.Snoopy! Because I think as long as you prune a network, the accuracy has to change since some trivial weights are set to zero so that the original network has to be affected which I think may lead to a drop in accuracy during the early epochs. Even if the changing is minor, there has to be a change. As far as I’m concerned, the reason why the accuracy remains unchanged is probably because the whole pruning process fails to function.